# How can I convert two lists into a dataframe, having one as a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I was getting my data from a yml file, so I could get two lists, like this:

one of the lists, named list_products, contains the name of the product:

```
['ABCD'
'LTAP'
'DEFG'
'FFEE']
```

The other, named list_ids, contains a list of ids and sometimes the element can be a list:

```
[[100, 200],
 [3333],
 [1500,99, 870],
 [2]]
```

When working only with list_ids, I could get a dataframe, this is the code I used:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in list_ids for item in sublist]
id_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list,columns=['id'])
```

And this was the result:

```
id
100
200
3333
1500
99
870
2
```

Now, I want to have a dataframe with the product name as well. I want to get this:

```
id       name
100      'ABCD'
200      'ABCD'
3333     'LTAP'
1500     'DEFG'
99       'DEFG'
870      'DEFG'
2        'FFEE'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can either pre-process the data using `zip` then build the DF

   ```
   names = ['ABCD', 'LTAP', 'DEFG', 'FFEE']
   list_ids = [[100, 200], [3333], [1500, 99, 870], [2]]

   flat_list = [(item, name) for sublist, name in zip(list_ids, names) for item in sublist]
   id_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list, columns=['id', 'name'])
   ```

   Intermediate `flat_list` is

   ```
   flat_list > [(100, 'ABCD'), (200, 'ABCD'), (3333, 'LTAP'), ...
   ```

---

2. Or build the df with raw data, then use `explode`

   ```
   id_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': list_ids, 'name': names}).explode('id')
   ```

   Intermediate `pd.DataFrame({'id': list_ids, 'name': names}`  is

   ```
                id  name
   0       [100, 200]  ABCD
   1           [3333]  LTAP
   2  [1500, 99, 870]  DEFG
   3              [2]  FFEE
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `explode`

```
l1 = ['ABCD',
'LTAP',
'DEFG',
'FFEE']
l2 = [[100, 200],
 [3333],
 [1500,99, 870],
 [2]]
out = pd.DataFrame({'col1':l1,'col2':l2}).explode('col2')
out
   col1  col2
0  ABCD   100
0  ABCD   200
1  LTAP  3333
2  DEFG  1500
2  DEFG    99
2  DEFG   870
3  FFEE     2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `explode` function as it is available only for `versions > 0.25`, you can use the below:

```
In [473]: d = {i : list_ids[c] for c, i in enumerate(named_list)}
In [474]: df_out = pd.DataFrame([(var, key) for (key, L) in d.items() for var in L], columns=['id', 'name'])

In [475] df_out
Out[475]: 
     id  name
0   100  ABCD
1   200  ABCD
2  3333  LTAP
3  1500  DEFG
4    99  DEFG
5   870  DEFG
6     2  FFEE
```